# For what values of $k$ does $(1+x)^{500+k}(1-x)^{500-k}$ exceed $10^9$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, computational-mathematics

Pretty simple question, for what values of $0\leq k \leq 500$ do we have $\max\{(1+x)^{500+k}(1-x)^{500-k}|x\in[0,1]\} \geq 10^9$ ?

Some trivial observations:

The problem is equivalent to finding the smallest $k$ so that $\max\{(1+x)^{500+k}(1-x)^{500-k}|x\in[0,1]\} < 10^9$

Clearly it is equal to $(1-x^{1000-2k})(1+x)^{2k}$ so we must have $(1+x)^{2k}\geq10^9$, since $1+x\leq 2$ this implies $2k\geq 30\implies k\geq 15$. Of course, this is probably useless.

---

Edit: Using the fact that maximum is reached at $\frac{k}{500}$ we can rephrase as:

$(500+k)^{500+k}(500-k)^{500-k}>500^{1000}10^9$

The following java problem solves this nicely in well under a second.

```
    import java.math.*;
public class eulerbla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger potdiez = new BigInteger ("1000000000");
        BigInteger quinmas = new BigInteger("500");
        BigInteger quinmen = new BigInteger("500");
        BigInteger num;
        BigInteger bound = quinmen.pow(1000);
        bound= bound.multiply(potdiez);
        for(int k=0;k<=500;k++){
            num = (quinmas.pow(500+k));
            num = num.multiply(quinmen.pow(500-k));
            if(num.compareTo(bound)>=0){
                System.out.println(k);
            }
            quinmas=quinmas.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            quinmen=quinmen.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        }

    }

}
```

Output:102

Comment: Maybe we should take the derivative?

Comment: Unless I made a mistake when deriving I think max is reached when $(1+x)(500-k)=(1-x)(500+k)$. I'm gonna solve the quadratic, I think the solution is $\frac{k}{500}$

Comment: Ok, thank MVW. So now we need to find for which $k$ we have$(\frac{500+k}{500})^{500+k}(\frac{500-k}{500})^{500-k}>10^9$ Which is equivalent to $(500+k)^{500+k}(500-k)^{500-k}>10^9500^{1000}$

Comment: This is clearly a big improvement, I'm gonna see if java's BigInteger class can handle it.

Comment: I made a mistake. Now I get $k/500$ for critical points as well. But that is still not the answer of the problem.

Comment: You can also write it as $(1+y)^{1+y}(1-y)^{1-y}>10^{9/500}$, with $y=k/500$

Comment: That leads to $k>101.44$

Comment: Yes, I just finished debugging my java code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Michael, how did you solve it?

Comment: From the equation in your third comment, take the 500th root.

Comment: no, I meant how did you get from your equation to 101.44

Comment: I couldn't solve the equation, but Wolfram Alpha did:y=0.2028778..

Comment: Oh I see, the only thing I didn't try to use it for was the only thing it could have helped me with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compute the critical point for $(1+x)^{500+k}(1-x)^{500-k}$: $x=\frac{k}{500}$. The value at this point is
$$
\left(1-\frac{k^2}{250000}\right)^{500}\left(\frac{500+k}{500-k}\right)^k
$$
For $k\lt500$, this is an increasing function of $k$, the derivative of its log is $\log\left(\frac{500+k}{500-k}\right)$, and computing values shows that for $102\le k\lt500$, $(1+x)^{500+k}(1-x)^{500-k}$ will be bigger than $10^9$ for $x=\frac{k}{500}$.

For $k\lt102$, $(1+x)^{500+k}(1-x)^{500-k}$ will not exceed $10^9$ on $[0,1]$.

---

We can approximate
$$
\overbrace{\left(1-\frac{k^2}{250000}\right)^{500}}^{\sim e^{-\frac{k^2}{500}}}\overbrace{\left(\frac{500+k}{500-k}\right)^k\vphantom{\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right)^5}}^{\sim e^{2\frac{k^2}{500}}}
\sim e^{\frac{k^2}{500}}
$$
If we solve
$$
e^{\frac{k^2}{500}}=10^9
$$
we get
$$
k=\sqrt{4500\log(10)}=101.792
$$

Comment: Thanks, how exactly does one plot stuff?

Comment: If $k$ is not small compared with $500$, the approximations may not be close.

Answer (score 1):

$\max\{(1+x)^{m+k}(1-x)^{m-k}|x\in[0,1]\} \geq 10^9
$

Set $m = 500$.

Let
$a(x, k)
= (1+x)^{m+k}(1-x)^{m-k}
$.

$\frac{a(x, k+1)}{a(x, k)}
=\frac{(1+x)^{m+k+1}(1-x)^{m-k-1}}{(1+x)^{m+k}(1-x)^{m-k}}
=\frac{1+x}{1-x}
\gt 1
$
so
$a(x, k)$
is increasing for all $k$.

Similarly,

$\begin{array}\\
a'(x, k)
&=(m+k)(1+x)^{m+k-1}(1-x)^{m-k}-(m-k)(1+x)^{m+k}(1-x)^{m-k-1}\\
&=(1+x)^{m+k-1}(1-x)^{m-k-1}((m+k)(1-x)-(m-k)(1+x))\\
&=(1+x)^{m+k-1}(1-x)^{m-k-1}((m+k)-(m-k)-x((m+k)+(m-k))\\
&=(1+x)^{m+k-1}(1-x)^{m-k-1}(2k-2mx)\\
&=0
\qquad\text{for }x = k/m\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
for fixed $k$,
$a(x, k)$
is max for
$x = k/m$.
At this $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
b(k, m)
&=a(k/m, k)\\
&=(1+k/m)^{m+k}(1-k/m)^{m-k}\\
&=\frac{(m+k)^{m+k}(m-k)^{m-k}}{m^{2m}}\\
\end{array}
$

If $k = cm$,
$0 < c < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
b(cm, m)
&=(1+c)^{m(1+c)}(1-c)^{m(1-c)}\\
&=\left((1+c)^{(1+c)}(1-c)^{(1-c)}\right)^m\\
\end{array}
$

To find where
$b(cm, m)
= 10^9$,
when $m = 500$,
we want
$g(c)
=10^{9/500}
\approx 1.042
$.

According to Wolfy,
this is about
$c=0.203$.
This corresponds to
$k = cm
=0.203\cdot 500
\approx 101.5
$.

This agrees fairly well
with your computation.